# in Firebase I am not able to upload image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

in firebase if I want to upload a file its not working perfectly, what is the mistake I did ,here I have use all the code in a one js file

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { initializeApp ,storage} from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/storage"
export default function Demo() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "VIzaSyDkgE2z3IIXr50AumPXmUfkoimM3f4z9d",
    authDomain: "reactform-95c40.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://reactform-65c50-default-rtd12.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "reactform-89c93",
    storageBucket: "reactform-67c52.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "793300985055",
    appId: "1:793300985055:web:aa37c4b76870f21f6d9a90"
  };
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const upload = (e)=>{
    if(search == null)
      return;
    storage.ref(search.name).put(search)
    .on("state_changed" , alert("success"));
  }
  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e)=>{setSearch(e.target.files[0]);console.log('loading...')}}/>
      <button onClick={(e)=>{upload(e)}}>Upload</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref') it indicate in line number 20 storage.ref...

Comment: [Start here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).